# File extension *.pag when compiling document with pdflatex and bibtex

Tags: auxiliary-files, filesystem-access, multiple-files

I'm compiling my document with `pdflatex` and `bibtex`, using the following command:

```
pdflatex main && bibtex main && pdflatex main && pdflatex main
```

This generated a couple of LaTeX file as expected, but I have a new `*.pag` file that wasn't in the [TeX gitignore file recommended here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/TeX.gitignore). And also this is the first time I'm seeing it too:

```
➜  paper_ijnmf git:(main) ✗ ls
AMA-stix  main.bbl  main.log  main.pdf  NJDnatbib.sty  references.bib    WileyNJD-v2.cls
main.aux  main.blg  main.pag  main.tex  README.md      WileyNJD-AMA.bst
```

What is PAG file? Can I exclude it from version control?

Comment: Since you show nothing of your document how are we suppose to know what it is. You seem to be on mac or Linux, have you tried running `file` on it or even had a look inside via `cat`

Comment: `WileyNJD-v2.cls` opens a file `\jobname.pag` (line 1265) to write some information on the page numbers. I guess, you could ignore it...

Comment: @DG' thanks I think that's the case. You can turn the comment into the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.pag`-file is created by the document class `WileyNJD-v2.cls`, it opens a file called `\jobname.pag` on line 1265, which contains some information on the page numbering.

It's save to add it to your `.gitignore`-file